# Laravel Eloquent OR WHERE IS NOT NULL

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent, administrator

I am using the Laravel Administrator package from frozennode. Long story short, I'm running into issues when displaying results that are soft-deleted. I'm trying to override the default query:

```
select * from `scripts` where `scripts`.`deleted_at` is null group by `scripts`.`id`
```

To display both deleted results and non-deleted, somehow hacking away. It's not the most elegant solution but I don't see any other way to do it. So, my goal is to do this:

```
select * from `scripts` where `scripts`.`deleted_at` is null or `scripts`.`deleted_at` is not null group by `scripts`.`id`
```

Unfortunately I don't know how to use orWhere() with 'is not null'. After researching a bit, I tried it with a raw SQL block, like this:

```
'query_filter'=> function($query) {
    $query->orWhere(DB::raw('`scripts`.`deleted_at` is not null'));
},
```

But I ended up with an extra piece of SQL resulting of not including the second parameter in orWhere():

```
select * from `scripts` where `scripts`.`deleted_at` is null or `scripts`.`deleted_at` is not null **is null** group by `scripts`.`id`
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Just add `withTrashed`:

```
'query_filter'=> function($query) {
    $query->withTrashed();
},
```

[Source](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#soft-deleting)

**Update**

In that case, you can probably just add a `orWhereNotNull()` call:

```
'query_filter'=> function($query) {
    $query->orWhereNotNull('deleted_at');
},
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I'm getting a Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::withTrashed() error.

Answer (score 1):

> Eloquent has a method for  (Laravel 4.* | 5.*):

`Model::whereNotNull('sent_at')`

> Laravel 3:
>   `Model::where_not_null('sent_at')`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search deleted record (Soft Deleted Record), don't user Eloquent Model Query.
Instead use `Db::table query`
e.g
Instead of using Below:

`$stu = Student::where('rollNum', '=', $rollNum . '-' . $nursery)->first();`

Use

`$stu = DB::table('students')->where('rollNum', '=', $newRollNo)->first();`

Answer (score -3):

This might be relevant:

```
return $this->join($table, $first, $operator, $second, 'right');
```

(from [GitHub)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L384).